# Possible cause of failure of Phonegap executeSql. Query is correct but sometimes it fails

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I'm working on a project that required to save signature(Image Base 64 ). Currently it's working fine but sometimes around 2% out of 100% failed due to unknown reason.

```
      $(document).ready(function() {    
            var db = window.openDatabase("TEST", "1.0", "TEST", 20000000 );
            db.transaction(insertSignature, errorCB, insertSignatureSuccess);

            function insertSignature(tx)
            {
                var signature               = $.trim($('#sig').val());
                var signature_laps          = $('#signature_laps').val();
                var signature_attempts      = $('#signature_attempts').val();
                var sql = 'UPDATE signature_table SET signature = "'+signature+'", signature_lap = "'+signature_laps+'", signature_attempt = "'+signature_attempts+'", modified_date = datetime("now", "localtime")' + 
                        ' WHERE cust_code = "'+cust_code+'" AND cycle_month = "'+month+'" AND cycle_year = "'+year+'"';
                tx.executeSql(sql);
            }

            function insertSignatureSuccess(tx)
            {
                alert('success');
            }

            function errorCB(err) 
            {
               alert('failed');
            }
    });
```

***WHERE***

**signature** variable contains base64 image

**signature_laps** & **signature_attempts** variable contains integers

**cust_code**, **month** & **year** are just important key parameters

***ON SQLITE***

**signature** field is BLOB

On 2% out of 100%, the 2% failure still says success even though the signature is not save but when i tried again with same stroke it successfully save. Why is it still proceeding on success message even the query is not successfully executed? It supposed to proceed on failed message. Is it a phonegap bug?

I'm running the phonegap under android ICS and jquery mobile.

Any idea? thanks guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the cause of the error or not, but with SQL commands u better state them as follows:

```
var sql='UPDATE signature_table SET signature = ?, signature_lap = ?, ' + 
'signature_attempt = ?, modified_date = datetime("now", "localtime") ' + 
'WHERE cust_code = ? AND cycle_month = ? AND cycle_year = ?';
tx.executeSql(sql, [signature, signature_laps, signature_attempts, cust_code, month, year]);
```

Also, seen this situation, it seems advisable to put the success- and callback functions in the transaction:

```
tx.executeSql(sql, [signature, signature_laps, signature_attempts, cust_code, month, year], insertSignatureSuccess, errorCB);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise. will try this another way and give you feedback. Currently I have my callback db.transaction(insertSignature, errorCB, insertSignatureSuccess);